# MySQL Add interger of multiple columns together as result

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to do a query like the following?

```
SELECT visits FROM analytics WHERE slug="0004c9a"
```

And the results would be

```
visits
6
5
```

And instead have it output only 1 row with the total of 11 (6+5)?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(visits) FROM analytics where slug="0004c9a"`

Comment: Thank you very much. I had issue formulating my question to find the right answer.

Comment: Use `slug='0004c9a'`  instead double qoutes normally means identifiers like database. table and columns in SQL.. Makes using a other RDMS besides MySQL much more easy..